Phantom differences when using visual studio schema compare for columns with default values
When using a sql database project (sqlproj) and doing a schema compare, columns with a default value are shown as being different, with the addition of parentheses around the default value.
  [IsValue] bit NOT Null DEFAULT(0),

shows as being different and looking like
  [IsValue] bit NOT Null DEFAULT ((0)) NOT NULL,

I've been manually ignoring this for years (across multiple versions of VS), is there any setting that will cause it to get that right and not add the extra pair of parentheses?  Updating the table doesn't appear to change anything, and the next time a comparison is done, it is again shown as being different.
